# How to write that as $X$ becomes more similar to $a$, $f(X)$ always becomes more similar to $z$

Tags: limits, notation, monotone-functions

What would be the ideal formal notation to express that, as a variable $X$ becomes more similar to number $a$, the function $f(X)$ **always** becomes more similar to number $z$?

As far as I understand, both the following two formal constructs are actually inaccurate:

- as $X \to a$, $f(X) \to z$
- $\lim\limits_{X \to a} f(X)=z$

The reason why I think they are both not accurate is that they guarantee only that when $X$ is arbitrarily close to $a$, $f(X)$ becomes arbitrarily close to $z$. Yet, they do not imply a monotonic relation, that is, they do not imply that as $X$ approximates $a$, $f(X)$ always gets closer to $z$.

Comment: Interesting question.  I disagree with your reaction, because I (arbitrarily) do not interpret "$f(x)$ *becomes more similar to number* $z$" as **requiring** that $f(x)$ is monotonic.  The remedy is **easy**, simply add monotonocity as a *further* requirement to $f(x).$  Note that you may (also) wish to **contrast** the idea of (for example) a function being **monotonically** increasing with the idea of a function being **strictly** increasing.  These are two **different** mathematical requirements.

Comment: For a (*perhaps very arguable*) counter example, let $f(x)$ be defined by $f(x) = x$ if $x$ is rational, else $f(x) = -x.$  Then you have the (perhaps subjective) debate whether as $x \to 0,$ $f(x)$ *becomes more similar to* $0$.

Comment: @user2661923 I think they were meant to say that the absolute error is monotonically decreasing.

Comment: @MarkS. "...they were meant to say...".  
Do you mean that the standard definition of convergence is supposed 
to (also) include the requirement that the absolute error is 
monotonically decreasing?  If so, this is the first that I've heard of 
this.  Every (*intuitive*) discussion of convergence that I've seen 
has been based on the idea of *neighborhoods*. ...see next comment

Comment: @MarkS.  Namely, for considering 
whether $f(x)$ converges to $f(a)$ as $x \to a,$ 
any $\epsilon, \delta$ discussion has been **limited** to indicating 
that if $x$ is in a neighborhood of $a$ of radius $\delta$, then 
$f(x)$ must be within a neighborhood of $f(a)$ of radius $\epsilon.$
Thus, the discussion(s) have (perhaps intentionally) permitted 
non-monotonic behavior within the $f(a)$ neighborhood of radius
$\epsilon.$

Comment: @user2661923 "Do you mean that the standard definition of convergence is supposed to (also) include the requirement that the absolute error is monotonically decreasing?" No. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, then I propose something like "For all $x_1,x_2$: $|x_2-a|<|x_1-a|\implies |f(x_2)-z|<|f(x_1)-z|$" If you also want the difference between $f$ and $z$ to get arbitrarily small, you could add "and $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to a}}f(x)=z$".

Comment: I have to ask, ...to what purpose?  For example, the standard definition of convergence and continuity allowed such subsequent results as if $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions, then so are $(f + g), (f \times g),$ and $|f|.$  What math problems could be more easily attacked by the requirement that (for example) as $x \to a$, the error term $|f(x) - f(a)|$ is monotonically decreasing?

Comment: @user2661923 I don't know. Don't ask me, ask 龙极限.